# Is it possible to color brackets/parenthesis in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

So I've recently been converted to Eclipse from Textpad [wow I didn't know what I was missing] and the only main complaint is I can't figure out how to how to get my brackets to be a different color.  I changed all the other colors to my old look so I guess my real problem is I can't add new rules to the list of different template items and brackets isn't in there by default.

I use PHP, here's the version of Eclipse:

```
Eclipse for PHP Developers

Build id: 20100218-1602
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to

`Windows > Preferences.`

Then navigate to

```
General > Editors > Structured Text Editors.
```

You'll find a list where you can adjust `Matching brackets highlights`.
Choose an intense color, as brackets are only highlighted by a thin outline.

EDIT:

It seems I misunderstood your request. What you are looking should is the font color of brackets. This should be placed in

```
PHP > Editor > Syntax Coloring
```

But there is yet no option to define a a different color for brackets or braces (like for Java)

Comment: Yes your edit is correct I checked in there but like you say nothing exists currently